# Why date validation in Google sheets rejects today's date before 8:00am?

Tags: validation, date, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've created a Google sheet to keep a list of work tasks with a column to track the date on which items are created, and built a script to automatically populate the cells in that column with the day's date when a new line is inserted.

The cell (e.g. G9) that is target of the script uses the following validation formula  to make sure that when users change the date, they use a date that is neither a weekend nor in the future:

`=and(isdate(G9), weekday(G9,2)<6, G9<=today())`

IT ONLY WORKS BUT ONLY IF THE SCRIPT IS RUN ANYTIME AFTER 8:00am !  If I try using it any earlier the cell validation will reject the input!

The script looks like this (curRow is the number of the row that's been added):

```
 // Adds today's date without using =today()
  var myrangename = "G"+curRow;
  var dateCell = sheet.getRange(myrangename);
  var d = new Date();
  var dateArr = [];
  dateArr[0]=d.getFullYear();
  dateArr[1]=d.getMonth() + 1; //Months are zero based
  dateArr[2]=d.getDate();
  dateCell.setValue(dateArr.join('/'));
```

(n.b.:  I cannot use the script to simply put `=today()` in the cell because all the entries would change every day. )

WHY DOES IT ONLY WORK AFTER 8:00AM? Is Google somehow running on a different time zone than my computer?? I'm based in the UK, so using `BST`, but that shouldn't be a problem, shouldn't it...?

Comment: what is it output of the script without validation + output of the formula `=today()` before 8AM?

Comment: Aprillion, looks like your instincts serve you well.  Before 8:00am, the output of the script after removing the cell's validation is "20/05/2015".  And the output of =today() is "19/05/2015"!  I've confirmed this by entering =now() as formula in another cell and that does show the date and time 8hrs behind what it should and right now 8hrs takes it back to yesterday.  So that means my Google sheet's "internal clock" is somehow running 8hrs behind!  Why??

Comment: perhaps there is a setting in google account / google documents and/or google+ about time zone that needs to be updated? you should probably talk to google's support I guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your suggestion, Aprillion.    Turns out that  **a Google Sheets file has its own internal time-zone setting!** which in my case was set to American Pacific time (so 8hrs behind)

(You'd think it would pick up the date and time info automatically from Windows, like other applications do!)
To set the sheet's time-zone to the correct one, you need to go to the main menu, click 'File', then 'Spreadsheet settings...', and adjust as necessary.
The script and validation now all work fine.
Thank you all for your help.

Comment: _You'd think it would pick up the date and time info automatically from Windows, like other applications do!_ It's not running in Windows, it's running on a server "in the cloud". So no, you wouldn't expect that.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var d = new Date();
var d = Utilities.formatDate(d, "GMT+1", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

I am not sure if google would recognise BST as a time zone, but you could also try

```
var d = Utilities.formatDate(d, "BST", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Comment: Akshin, I've tried your suggestion, both with GMT and BST, but neither worked. I suspect it's something to do with Google Sheet's "internal clock"